# Как сделать, чтобы заголовок статьи был ссылкой на страницу с этой статьёй и ссылку "Читать далее"?

Tags: php, mysql

я сделал на своём сайте вывод статей на главную страницу, но это неудобно т.к заголовок статьи должен быть ссылкой на страницу с этой статьёй. Ещё нужно, чтобы после определённого количества символов появлялась ссылка "Читать далее". Как это можно реализовать?
Типа так:

[image: 123]

Как тут правильно точки и запятые расставить:

```
echo '<h2>'. '<a href = "admin.php?id=
{$row['id']}>".$row['title'].'.'</a>' '</h2>'.'</h2><br>'. 
$row['date'].'<p><h4>' . $row['content'] . '</p></h4>';
```

Вот:

```
$id = $row['id'];
    echo  '<h2>'. '<a href = "admin.php?id=$id">'.$row['title'].' </a></h2><br>'. $row['date'].'<p><h4>' . $row['content'] . '</p></h4>';
```

Comment: Конкретная проблема в чем? Ссылка выводится так `<a href="url">Вперед</a>`. Вместо `url` вставляй нужный урл.

Comment: @u_mulder  echo '<h2>'. '<a href = "admin.php?id={$row['id']}>".$row['title'].'.'</a>' '</h2>'.'</h2><br>'. $row['date'].'<p><h4>' . $row['content'] . '</p></h4>'; как тут правильно точки и запятые расставить?

Comment: Код в комментариях __нечитабелен__, отредактируй вопрос.

Comment: @u_mulder  отредактировал

Comment: ппц. Для вас, видать, магия прям какая-то конкатенация строк.

Comment: @ArchDemon как правильно сделать?

Comment: Почитать документацию и правильно расставить точки и кавычки. Воспользоваться функцией `sprintf`

Comment: @ArchDemon всё получилось, я разобрался. https://ibb.co/dQMZHRn

Comment: @ArchDemon только как теперь сделать, чтобы при переходе по ссылке пользователь переходил на статью

Comment: Написать соответствующий код на сервере. Который получает значение `$_GET['id']` и выводит нужную статью

Comment: @ArchDemon Как это сделать? Откуда брать $_GET['id']? Из url? Я отредактировал вопрос, написал свой код для вывода статьи из url, но он не работает

Comment: Может сделать отдельный php файл, на который будет перенаправлен пользователь. В этом файле будет вывод статьи исходя из url? Только как это сделать?

Comment: Я попробовал так: https://github.com/1yaroslav/class.forms.php/blob/main/my.php -не получилось просто пустая страница

Comment: Время __включить отображение ошибок__ и задать себе вопрос - какое значение у переменной `$conn`?